# How to Translate a webpage with googletrans API in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request, google-translate

```
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()

url = 'http://www.compactrb.ro/'

page = requests.get(url)

translated = translator.translate(page.text)

print(translated)
```

My code looks something like this, I want to get the webpage using the requests library and I want to translate this webpage into English. This webpage is in Romanian, I want to perform scraping on this website but first I want to convert the webpage into English.
This code does not work it gives me this error : ***TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType*** . If there is another way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The default googletrans package has not been updated in years and currently has a bug in it.

You can fix this by installing the alpha release: `pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0`

I've tested and it works with the alpha version.

You can follow the discussion / updates here: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234#issuecomment-742460612

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

files_from_folder = r"e:\Carte\Translate"

use_translate_folder = False

destination_language = 'fr'

extension_file = ".html"

import os

directory = os.fsencode(files_from_folder)
```

See the complete code [HERE](https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html)